# not able to get ng-bind-html dropdown value on ng-click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i new to **Angularjs** i can do this in **Jquery** but i want to learn **angularjs**.

i have dropdown were im using `ng-bind-html`  to get dropdown value and updating that value to that `ng-bind-html` it is working fine.
but when i select the value from dropdown and console it in console log it is showing as null.

but when i update the dropdown with hardcode value and select the value then it is coming correctly on log.

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="addComplaintCtrl">
 <select class="form-control" id="product_name" name="product_name" ng-model="product_name" ng-bind-html="pdl">
     <!--<option value="">-Select-</option>
     <option value='00'>Other</option>-->
  </select>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="complaintSubmitEvent();" value="Submit Complaint">
 </div> 

 </div>
```

Angular Code:

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngSanitize']);

  app.controller("addComplaintCtrl",function($scope,$sce){

  $scope.pdl=$sce.trustAsHtml('<option value="">-Select-</option><option value="Sales" >Sales</option>');

  $scope.complaintSubmitEvent=function(){
        //alert(0);
        console.log($scope.product_name);

  }

  })
  </script>
```

below is jsfiddle link.
[ng-bind-html](https://jsfiddle.net/ajitrishabh/12mg0cmy/6/)

Comment: @Satpal pls check jsfiddle link. if u still want to see code here i can put.

Comment: now i have added the code pls check @Satpal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compile the change made by `ng-bind-html`  you can create a directive something like

```
app.directive('compile',function($compile, $timeout){
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
            $timeout(function(){                
                $compile(elem.contents())(scope);    
            });
        }        
    };
});
```

`$timeout` is used to run compile function, after `ng-bind-html` do its job

Now you can just simply put compile as attribute of select with ng-bind-html

```
<select class="form-control" id="product_name" name="product_name" ng-model="product_name" ng-bind-html="pdl" compile >
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y19at48o/2/)

Comment: thanks @jitender. so whereever if a im using ng-bind-html i have to compile the code?

Comment: You need to compile dynamically created elements to let angular know about them. Initially angular doesn't know about the options those were added later on by `ng-bind-html` so you have to let angular know about them

Comment: it is not working on my main code. it is something to do with $timeout. content is taking some time to load

Comment: try adding 1 sec delay in `$timeout`

Comment: Yes 1 sec delay helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also dynamically add `options` to `select` using `ng-repeat` if you do not want to use `ng-bind-html`. Here is the working code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="addComplaintCtrl">
<select class="form-control" id="product_name" name="product_name" ng-model="product_name">
      <option ng-repeat="d in dropdownData" value="{{d.value}}">{{d.name}}</option>
</select>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="complaintSubmitEvent();" value="Submit Complaint">
</div>     
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngSanitize']);

    app.controller("addComplaintCtrl",function($scope,$sce){
    $scope.dropdownData = [{name:'-select-', value:''},{name: 'sales', value:'sales'}];

    $scope.complaintSubmitEvent=function(){
        //alert(0);
        console.log($scope.product_name);

    }
});
</script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9afyrqsf/)